# instance vs local variables in a partial

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently going through Michael Hartl's tutorial Ruby on Rails Tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.  I'm confused about where certain partial variables come from.  In his tutorial he creates Users and Microposts.  A User can create a Micropost on his main page (called a Feed) and have them posted there.  The layout looks like this http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#fig:proto_feed_mockup.  Now the User model looks like this (I'm not posting the entire thing):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy

  def feed
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end
end
```

The Micropost model looks like this:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In the text the author says that the feed method inside the User model can be written equivalently like this:

```
def feed
  microposts
end
```

Why are they the same?

My next questions have to do with partials.  On the user's show page (show.html.erb) the _microposts.html.erb is called with this if I'm not mistaken:

```
<%= render @microposts %>
```

_microposts.html.erb looks like this:

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
      title: micropost.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

My question here is where is the micropost variable come from?  Is it the same as the @micropost variable which calls this partial?

Now on the users home page (home.html.erb) there is a call to the _feed.html.erb partial like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/feed' %>
```

_feed.html.erb looks like this:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

I know where @feed_items comes from.  It's set in a controller.  Now _feed_item.html.erb looks like this:

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
      title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

So a similar question is where does the variable feed_item come from and what does it contain?

thanks,
mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's see. This is a lot of questions in one go, but...

1. Why is 'feed' equivalent to 'microposts'?
   This is Rails' associations at work. When you use `has_many` to describe an association, Rails creates a whole bunch of methods based on the association name. In this case, you say that User `has_many :microposts`, which, among others, creates a `User#microposts` method.
2. The instance variable used in the render call (`@microposts`) is presumably set in a controller action. When you call render in this fashion (with an array of ActiveRecord objects), Rails looks for a partial with a name matching the class name of those objects. In this case, they're MicroPost objects, so it looks for a partial named `_micropost` and renders it once for each object in the array. When rendering a partial, the object that the partial is associated with can be referred to using a local variable with the same name as the partial. Since this is the `_micropost` partial, the local `micropost` variable refers to the object it's rendering.
3. Once again, the local variable with the same name as the partial refers to the object the partial is rendering. @feed_items is a collection, and for each object in it, you get one rendering of the `_feed_item` partial, in which the `feed_item` local variable refers to that object.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because a user's microposts are associated using `has_many`, and internally, the relationship is based on the user's id. Getting them "by hand" does essentially the same thing, but with more work.
2. `micropost` comes from convention–Rails creates it for you. I don't know what you mean by "the `@micropost` variable which calls this partial".
3. Same answer, although it's based explicitly on the template name (IIRC) rather than a singularized name. It contains a single one of whatever `@feed_items` contains.